# Images not displayed on corresponding xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode9-beta

I have created empty application in xcode .Then i created two view controller with xib.Then i placed images background using interface builder login.jpg on loginBIDViewController.xib and home.jpeg on ESBPBIDViewController.xib.I have set the necessary constraints . On running the project .Simulator doesn't displays those images on corresponding xib .I do not understand the reason behind this simple step[image].Here is link for of sample code for correction.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SncGFuaDd0dkpUOE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try with using images 2x and 3x or use imageAssets.

Comment: Updated my answer below. pls check.

Comment: can you show mi login img jpg attribute inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Go to Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Add login.jpg to the list.

This will display the image on view.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Add login.jpg and home.jpg[image]

[image]